# In Swift a CPU heavy task freezes the app for a few seconds - GLTFSceneKit

Tags: swift, gltf

In my project, I started using the GLTFSceneKit package to load models. It works perfectly, but there is a method that causes the UI to freeze for 1-2 seconds, and then everything continues.

The code is as follows:

```
import GLTFSceneKit

var scene: SCNScene
do {
  let sceneSource = try GLTFSceneSource(named: "art.scnassets/Box/glTF/Box.gltf")
  scene = try sceneSource.scene()
} catch {
  print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
  return
}
```

I noticed that the `scene = try sceneSource.scene()` line is responsible for the freeze.

How can I fix it so that the app doesn't freeze when it gets to this line of code?

Comment: Try wrapping the call in an async function an call it using a Task and see if that helps